# AdvTree selected node c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetbar

I've selected a node which has data of different columns. some of the columns are set as visible = false.

When i drag and drop it from first AdvTree to the 2nd AdvTree, the hidden column are displayed.

How do i make it such that only the visible column are dropped onto the other AdvTree control?

I want to make it such that when i drag the selected node to the other AdvTree, i'll populate the advtree with visible columns on the first advTree + additional columns (dropdown selection)

Comment: This question is quite unclear.
Could you be more specific. Are you using Winform, WPF or a web project? What is AdvTree.
Please add the right tags to your question.

Comment: sorry this is a component from dotnetbar, im doing a c# winform application

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best choice will be to catch the drop event on advTree2 and hide the columns from code.